# How do I get rotate gesture to continue spin once state has ended?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I am using the code below to try and get my recognizer to continue spinning after the state has ended.  It only seems to get one rotation no matter how high I set the value in the CGAffineTransformRotate.

Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:6.55];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, 1000000000);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Conceptual correction: You can't set the rotation value super-high and have that be equivalent to multiple rotations. You're creating an affine transform, which is a fixed matrix. It doesn't know how to say "keep going"-- the rotation you create is basically "mod 360 degrees". See @thelaws' answer for a better technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try to use a `CABasicAnimation`

```
- (void)rotate {

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

CABasicAnimation *animation;
animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.delegate = self;
[recognizer.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

[CATransaction commit];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)finished {
if (finished) 
    [self rotate];  
}
```

This will cause the rotation to continue until you specify to remove the animation.

There's more infomation and options in the [CABasicAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) Class Reference

Comment: This is all fine and dandy, but it's going to be a nightmare to set up a natural feeling spin, lol. Thumbs up for effort though.